# Laravel one-to-one relationship not associating

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've got two models, Template and State that are associated via a one-to-one relationship. The State belongs to the Template,

A foreign key is created using the following migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table(
        'templates',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('state');

            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('template_states');
        }
    );
}
```

Then, the Template model class defines the state field as a hasOne relationship:

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->hasOne('TemplateState', 'id', 'state_id');
}
```

and the TemplateState model class defines the inverse belongs to bit with:

```
public function template()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Template');
}
```

I'm having great difficulty associating the state with it's template once created in the DB. Take a look at the following Tinker:

```
[1] > $t = Template::find(1);
// object(Template)(
//   'incrementing' => true,
//   'timestamps' => true,
//   'exists' => true
// )
[2] > $t->alias;
// 'travel_journal'
[3] > $s = TemplateState::find(1);
// object(TemplateState)(
//   'incrementing' => true,
//   'timestamps' => true,
//   'exists' => true
// )
[4] > $s->state;
// 'pending'
[5] > $t->state()->save($s);
// object(TemplateState)(
//   'incrementing' => true,
//   'timestamps' => true,
//   'exists' => true
// )
[6] > $t->state->state;
```

At step [6] of the tinker, calling $t->state->state, I can see there's no association made with the two models, and looking in the database, the state_id for the template is still null.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, can anyone please help!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working by changing the following:

State Model:

```
public function template()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Template');
}
```

Template Model:

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->hasOne('TemplateState');
}
```

and adding the foreign key to the TemplateState model instead.

Now, calling something like:

```
$template->state()->save($state);
```

works fine.

Comment: Make sure it really does what you suppose

Comment: Thanks @deczo. I'm 100% certain it's working. The system is able to properly associate templates with their related state. Playing around in tinker, it's appears everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Your relations are wrong, this is what you need:

```
// Template model
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('TemplateState', 'state_id');
}

// TemplateState model
public function template()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Template', 'state_id');
}
```

Comment: I'm understanding that you're saying I should make Template belong to TemplateState, so reverse what I currently have?

Comment: Yes I do, `hasOne`/`hasMany` requires foreign key on the other table, which is opposite to `belongsTo`.